# How to get status of a job running on another machine?

Tags: python, request, remote-server, job-scheduling

I have 2 machines A and B and A can send restful request to B as follows:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"data":"python /tmp/demo.py","action":"demo"}' 'http://192.168.95.8:51888/api/host'
```

I have deployed an api service on B and when such request is received, B will execute the python script `/tmp/demo.py` and the execution may last 0.5-3 hours.

My question is:

1) How to write a job on A that keeps tracking the status of the task running on B and end it self when the task finishes successfully or failed?

2)  In the tracking job, how to add a module that can kill itself after exceeding a pre-set time threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the job as an HTTP resource. When you do `POST /api/host`, that request creates a new id for that job and returns it. For good use of HTTP, the response would contain a `Location` header with the URL of the resource where the job's status can be checked, e.g.:

```
POST /api/hosts
Content-type: application/json

{"data":"python /tmp/demo.py","action":"demo"}
```

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /api/host/jobs/c2de232b-f63e-4178-a053-d3f3459ab538
```

You can now `GET /api/host/jobs/c2de232b-f63e-4178-a053-d3f3459ab538` at any time and see what status the job has, e.g.:

```
{"status": "pending"}
```

You may `POST` commands to that resource, e.g. for cancelling it.

How exactly your HTTP API would get the status of that Python script is obviously up to you. Perhaps it can communicate with it over a socket, or the job itself will periodically write its status to some database or file.

Comment: wow looks magical to me...could you give more details on how is the location part `/job/xxx` generated and how to post commands via the `location`?

Comment: That’s a random UUID for the sake of this example. How exactly you’re going to do it depends on your situation. How to do the posting part depends on how exactly you’re going to implement that web service; that’s a bit too broad to address in detail. But you’re just going to make a POST request to that URL, nothing special about it.

Comment: Hi. The last question is how does the task get the status of itself (pending/running/success...)?